# Objective-C get image from web page

Tags: javascript, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I need to retrieve an image (the src of an img tag) contained in a web page (html file). The web page may contain more than one images, I just need to retrieve any of them (lets say the first one).
Till now I've gone so far:

```
UIWebView * tmpWV;
tmpWV = [[UIWebView alloc] init];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:page_url];
NSURLRequest * req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[tmpWV loadRequest:req];

NSString *img = [tmpWV stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src;"];
[tmpWV release];
tmpWV = nil;
```

Unfortunately this code doesn't seem to work, when I try to see the contents of img in the console, the output is nothing. I've tested the JavaScript code separately and it is working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you dump img to the console, does it contain the URL for the image or is it empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supply a `UIWebViewDelegate` to your WebView and put the logic inside a `webViewDidFinishLoad` method.

Answer (score 2):

You're neglecting the fact that http requests don't happen instantaneously.  You'll need to register a callback when the request is finished loading, then try to parse for your image.